# Meteor Cordova run ios / android minifies js and css

Tags: cordova, meteor, meteor-cordova

I'm using Meteor 1.5.0 developing android and ios apps on my mac.
I have adb, android studio, XCode, safari and chrome running properly on my system.

After plugging in my android phone, I run the following command:

```
meteor run android-device --settings private/settings.json
```

The app runs properly on my device, however, when I debug in chrome (using Remote Devices within the developer tools), the js and css files appear to be minified. I can't find the original js files.

This happens on the ios emulator as well (when I try debugging with Safari).

I tried running the command with --debug option but just get an 'unknown option' error. (I assume that option is only valid when building an app, not running it).

I've also added the following to my app:

```
if(Meteor.isCordova) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
};
```

But this doesn't seem to help.

I've read the documents and it appears that meteor run is not supposed to minify the js / css files. However, it appears that's precisely what's happening in my project. Has anyone run into this problem?